# Given an IF-ELSE statement inside a for loop, can I only skip the IF when the condition is met once? python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, spacy

Below is a function that marks verbs in sentences by adding an 'X' at the end of the verb word. This is done using spaCy for POS tagging. The function has an if-else statement inside a for loop (see below). The if statement checks whether a word is a verb to be marked, or not.

However, I want to be able to skip the IF part once an `n` number of verbs has been found, and then only continue running with the rest of the function. I am aware this might be a simple or silly question and tried a while loop and `continue` but could not get this working. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
def marking(row):
    chunks = []
    for token in nlp(row):
        if token.tag_ == 'VB': 
        # I would like to specify the n number of VB's to be found
        # once this is met, only run the else part
            chunks.append(token.text + 'X' + token.whitespace_)
        else:
            chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)
    L = "".join(chunks)
    return L
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a counter and a `break`

```
def marking(row, max_verbs=5):
    chunks = []
    verbs = 0
    for token in nlp(row):
        if token.tag_ == 'VB':
            if verbs >= max_verbs:
                break  # Don't add anymore, end the loop
            chunks.append(token.text + 'X' + token.whitespace_)
            verbs += 1
        else:
            chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)
    return "".join(chunks)
```

Call it by `marking(row, max_verbs=N)`

Comment: Thanks! This works. There is only one problem left (perhaps my question was not 100% clear). If N = 1 (for example) a second verb VB will be skipped entirely by the function. However, the verb should still be added to `chunks` in the `else` part `chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)` - just without the X. Is that possible? Perhaps replacing `break` with `chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)` would work, I think.

Comment: I left that second else statement in there for that purpose

Comment: When running your code above, part of the sentence is not added to `chunk` when `verbs > max_verbs`. Therefore, I have eliminated `break` and added a second `else: chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)` so that the verb is still added to the sentence when `verbs > max_verbs`. Now it works. Thanks so much.